# f(x) = 1 for -0.5<X<0.5 otherwise 0, need to define this function and plot the function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
f(x) = 1 for -0.5< X <0.5 
         otherwise 0.
```

I want to define this function and plot the function in MATLAB within the interval -10 to 10.

Comment: Why don't you start here: [Getting Started with MATLAB](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html). And if you have more questions, also read that : [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
x = linspace(-10, 10, 1000);
fx = ( x > -0.5 ) & ( x < 0.5 );
figure;
plot( x, fx );
```